# Restore C: drive converted to swap area in dual boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, multi-boot

I attempted to dual boot my laptop with Linux Mint and accidentally converted my C:\ drive to swap area. After being unable to revert my changes, I tried booting Windows and could not use any of the advanced options to restore my computer, including resetting the OS and restoring from a system restore point.

So is there any way to convert my swap area (which does not register as a drive even in other copies of windows) to an NTFS file system? Preferably without losing files, but I recognize that that's probably impossible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you format a partition, the data stored on it is practically gone. You'll either need some specialty hardware to recover the data (this is not a 100% fix and might very well fail) or accept the fact that you've lost your data and reformat the disk to something that you can use.

Your best bet would be to re-install Windows, I'm afraid.